# Extracting dates that satisfied multiple conditions using NCO/CDO or bash

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

I have a netcdf file containing vorticity (per sec) and winds (m/s). I want to print the dates of gridpoints that satisfy the following conditions:

1). Vorticity > 1x10^-5 per sec and winds >= 5 m/s at a gridpoint.

2). The average of vorticity and winds at the "four" (North, West, East, South) surrounding the gridpoint found in (1) should also be > 1x10^-5 and 5m/s, respectively.

I am able to just filter the gridpoints that satisfied (1), using ncap:

```
ncap2 -v -O -s 'where(vort > 1e-5 && winds >= 5) vort=vort; elsewhere vort=vort.get_miss();' input_test.nc output_test.nc
```

How do I get the dates? Also how can I implement the second condition.

Here's the screenshot of the header of the netcdf file.

[image]

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the NetCDF data you have, it would be difficult to get a proper answer. I think you need to show at least the NetCDF header or some other information that shows the structure of the data.

Comment: Do you want to display the date at that time if there is at least one grid that satisfies the conditions 1) and 2)?

Comment: yes @binzo..I'll update my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be achieved by combining "cdo" and "nco".

The average value of the surrounding 4 grids needed for the second condition can be calculated by combining the `shiftxy` and `ensmean` operators of "cdo".

```
cdo selname,vr,wspd input_test.nc vars.nc
cdo -expr,'vr_mean=vr; wspd_mean=wspd' \
      -ensmean \
        -shiftx,1  vars.nc \
        -shiftx,-1 vars.nc \
        -shifty,1  vars.nc \
        -shifty,-1 vars.nc \
    vars_mean.nc
```

You can then use `merge` operator of "cdo" to combine the variables needed to check conditions 1) and 2) into a single NetCDF file, and use ncap2 to check the conditions as you have tried.

In the example command below, the "for" loop of "ncap2" is used to scan the time. If there is at least one grid that satisfies both conditions 1) and 2) at each time, the information for that time will be displayed.

```
cdo merge vars.nc vars_mean.nc vars_test.nc
ncap2 -s '*flag = (vr > 1e-5 && wspd >= 5) && (vr > 1e-5 && wspd >= 5); *nt=$time.size; for(*i=0;i<nt;i++) { if ( max(flag(i,:,:))==1 ) { print(time(i)); } }' vars_test.nc
```